# Click on desired coordinates without mouse opencv

Tags: opencv, windows-7, mouseevent

I am working on a project in which I am fetching image from camera and saving the gestures made by users.
Now if the input gesture matches the saved gesture, I want to click my mouse ( left , right both ).

So I am asking if there is any inbuilt function in windows.h or in opencv like LBUTTONDOWN(10,10). Which left clicks at coordinate (10,10) when called.

I am using opencv 2.4.2 with codeblocks on windows 7 platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for [SendInput function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The SendInput function inserts the events in the INPUT structures
>   serially into the keyboard or mouse input stream.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCV, you can use `setMouseCallback()` to set mouse handler for the specified window. See [here](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.hk/2011/11/mouse-events.html) for code example.